# c# Can I override .NET StreamWriter.WriteLine() to return what it wrote instead of void?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, overriding

I am a proficient but not expert OOP programmer.  I know class methods can be overridden to alter the default behaviour.

I have it in mind to overload a .NET class method itself, and override the `StreamWriter.WriteLine(string str, bool APPEND)` method to return whatever it was asked to write instead of returning `void`.

This because I have to log to a file, and the console both, and the string I am writing is a complex expression that I do not want to have to duplicate, nor do I want to consume additional resources (and add aditional lines of code) to create a baggage variable just for the purpose of console and log file logging in every one of the dozens of places where I write to the console and the log file.

Instead of this:

```
Console.WriteLine(a + b + c + d + e);
sw.WriteLine(a + b + c + d + e);
```

Or this:

```
string temp = a + b + c + d + e;

Console.WriteLine(temp);
sw.WriteLine(temp);
```

I instead want to do this:

```
Console.WriteLine(
    sw.WriteLine(a + b + c + d + e)
);
```

To do this, I need the sw.WriteLine() method to return it's string parameter as a return value.

I understand the dangers involved in overriding methods, but this is a very simple, one module `.cs` console app that is just searching text files and reporting matching lines to the console and log file.

When I use the object browser (peek definition) in Visual Studio, I see:

```
public static void WriteLine(string format, object arg0);
public static void WriteLine(string format, params object[] arg);
public static void WriteLine(char[] buffer, int index, int count);
public static void WriteLine(decimal value);
public static void WriteLine(char[] buffer);
public static void WriteLine(char value);
public static void WriteLine(bool value);
public static void WriteLine(string format, object arg0, object arg1);
public static void WriteLine(double value);
```

That first method seems to have the signature I want to override.

But all these methods only have comments.  No code.  (My guess, probably because they are .NET internal classes compiled into .dlls, without the code distributed).

**Can what I want to do be done?  And if so, how?**

If not, can you suggest an alternate approach?

Comment: That's the object browser for Console and not StreamWriter (evidenced by the static methods). But anyways, you can't override and change the return type (except for covariant returns, which void cannot be) so you're out of luck there

Comment: I do not understand why you do not simply create a method that writes to both the console and streamwriter? You could have it also return the `string`. I may have misread something, but I do not understand why this option is a non-starter.

Comment: @JohnG - That is exactly my plan if it turns out that this can't (or shouldn't) be done.  ;-)  Thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't override it but you could create an extension method for each variant of WriteLine which you want to have e.g.

```
public static class StreamWriterExtensions
{
    public static string WriteLine(this StreamWriter s, string value)
    {
        s.WriteLine(value);
        return value;
    }

    public static string WriteLineToStreamAndConsole(this StreamWriter s, string value)
    {
        s.WriteLine(value);
        Console.WriteLine(value);
        return value;
    }
}
```

And use like so:

```
streamWriter.WriteLineToStreamAndConsole(a + b + c);
```

Or you could simply do it in a private method where you need it.

```
private void WriteLineToStreamAndConsole(StreamWriter s, string value)
{
    s.WriteLine(value);
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Comment: `LogToStreamAndConsole` would be the best solution in my opinion

Comment: Yes, that was exactly my plan if it turned out this can't be done, or is a bad idea.  Thanks. ;-)